# How to access hidden properties of scrollbar in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I realized the object I want to make in my game has most of the same properties as a scrollbar. How would I go about recognizing it as a normal object and modifying the bar's original default properties?

Comment: Please, for the people to help you in the best way, you should provide the code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RolandLariotte, as we see, he just want code plz. If you have some, could you please a share with him? :)